# Why does using .match inside of an ng-if seem to cause digest cycles

Tags: angularjs

Consider the following simple angularjs app (fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/jeconner/n3e61o0a/33/):

```html
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-if="showVal()">
    {{val}}
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.val = 0;
    
    $interval(function () {
        $scope.val = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 200);
    }, 1000);
    
    $scope.showVal = function () {
        //return $scope.val % 2 == 0; // This works!
        return String($scope.val).match(/[1]{1}[0-9]{2}/); // Console errors!
    };
}
```

The value of `val` is set to change every second. If you uncomment the first return line in `showVal`, this runs without error, showing `val` when it is even.

However, if you convert `val` to a string and test against a regex like the one above, there is a console error complaining about 10 digest cycles being reached:

> "Error:
> [$rootScope:infdig 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
> Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [&quot;showVal(); newVal:
> [\"176\"]; oldVal:
> [\"176\"]&quot;],[&quot;showVal(); newVal:
> [\"176\"]; oldVal:
> [\"176\"]&quot;],[&quot;showVal(); newVal:
> [\"176\"]; oldVal:
> [\"176\"]&quot;],[&quot;showVal(); newVal:
> [\"176\"]; oldVal:
> [\"176\"]&quot;],[&quot;showVal(); newVal:
> [\"176\"]; oldVal: [\"176\"]&quot;]
> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.1/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22showVal()%3B%20newVal%3A%20%5B%5C%22176%5C%22%5D%3B%20oldVal%3A%20%5B%5C%22176%5C%22%5D%22%5D%2C%5B%22showVal()%3B%20newVal%3A%20%5B%5C%22176%5C%22%5D%3B%20oldVal%3A%20%5B%5C%22176%5C%22%5D%22%5D%2C%5B%22showVal()%3B%20newVal%3A%20%5B%5C%22176%5C%22%5D%3B%20oldVal%3A%20%5B%5C%22176%5C%22%5D%22%5D%2C%5B%22showVal()%3B%20newVal%3A%20%5B%5C%22176%5C%22%5D%3B%20oldVal%3A%20%5B%5C%22176%5C%22%5D%22%5D%2C%5B%22showVal()%3B%20newVal%3A%20%5B%5C%22176%5C%22%5D%3B%20oldVal%3A%20%5B%5C%22176%5C%22%5D%22%5D%5D
> at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js:78:12
> at Scope.$digest (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js:11472:19)
> at Scope.$apply (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js:11682:24)
> at tick (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js:8189:36)"]
> "Script error."

Why does this error occur? Is there a proper way for using regex inside of an ng-if that avoids this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try not to have functions as my ng-show or ng-if. They get called non-stop, often unnecessarily. I have found it's alot easier on memory and performance to use booleans that are set behind the scenes. For example, in your code it's setting `$scope.val` every second, but might be running the showVal() function many,  many times during digests. Consider this alternate, which I tested in a fiddle without errors:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-if="showValBool">
    {{val}}
  </div>
</div>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.val = 0;
    $scope.showValBool = false
    $interval(function () {
        $scope.val = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 200);
        $scope.showValBool = String($scope.val).match(/[1]{1}[0-9]{2}/);
    }, 1000);
    
}
```